# SDCard not accurate

Tags: android

I am working on a basic music player that will obtain the songs on the SDCard. It is at its early stages and I've encountered a slight problem. Whenever I run the app on my phone it gets the songs on the SDCard great. Now when I run the app on my teachers phone it gets the internal storage directory and not the SDCard path. I have implemented the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory and it still returns the content on the interal memory. Is there a way I can fix this problem?? Oh and by the way my teacher's phone is a Samsung S3.

Comment: You've likely mis-stated the problem, in effect "External Storage" does not mean what it at first glance seems to.  On the "problem" phone the program is still listing the contents of the "External Storage" however that is implemented using permanently soldered flash memory.  You want instead to access an "external SD card", a distinct and optional concept which is unfortunately not implemented in consistent ways across devices.

Comment: The documentation states that `getExternalStorageDirectory` returns some form of relatively large storage space considered as primary. It also mentions the existence of secondary storages, but the documentation does not explain how. Oddly, the sentence is stopped in the middle.

Comment: so there is no direct solution to get the external sdcard path for the Samsung S3?? How odd because it does work on my phone like a charm...

Comment: I expect there's an API which works on that device, and scanning /proc/mounts will find all the options on any device, but indeed there is no solution to finding storage locations which is simple, portable, and universal.

Answer (score 2):

> so there is no direct solution to get the external sdcard path for the Samsung S3?

No. Moreover, you should not need it. A "basic music player that will obtain the songs" should be using `MediaStore`, not scanning external storage directly. Not only will it be faster, but on many devices, `MediaStore` will have indexed alternative storage locations (e.g., removable media) for you.

Comment: yea I've read about the media store. I'm new to android programming android so i'm not acquainted with the environment. What I've read about the media store is not quite explainable for my experience so that's why I have not implemented it. Do you know any tutorials that can explain the usage of the media store??

Comment: @user3191857: http://bhargavvasani.blogspot.com/2013/07/android-audio-file-list-with-play-and.html is one that comes up via a search engine. You may also want to read [the documentation on `ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html), as that is what `MediaStore` is.

Comment: okay thank you for the information I'm going to take a look at those sites.